# Spring-boot BOM does not contain a dependency for tomcat-dbcp

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

[Spring-boot BOM](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies) does not contain a dependency for [tomcat-dbcp](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-dbcp).

I have a Spring MVC project where I use a database connection pool for Hibernate ORM connections. This project is deployed in Tomcat. In my IntelliJ Idea development environment I use Tomcat embedded, by using the [spring-boot-starter-tomcat](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat). But the spring-boot-starter-tomcat does not define a dependency to tomcat-dbcp. Hence I decided to explicitly define a dependency to tomcat-dbcp in my build.gradle.kts file.

I had hoped that the Spring-boot BOM would have contained tomcat-dbcp, so that I would not need to specify it's version number and rely on the Spring Boot dependency management system to handle it's version number for me. But the Spring-boot BOM does not contain a dependency for tomcat-dbcp. Can Spring-Boot add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following hack so as to not hard code the version number for tomcat-dbcp. Just added the following code to the build.gradle.kts file after dependencies section.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
        if (requested.group == "org.apache.tomcat.embed" && requested.name == "tomcat-embed-core") {
            dependencies {
                providedRuntime("org.apache.tomcat", "tomcat-dbcp", requested.version)  //to use tomcat connection pool in tomcat embedded mode.
            }
        }
    }
}
```